# SpringBoot Microservice vs aws lambda

Tags: rest, aws-lambda, microservices, aws-api-gateway, amazon-ecs

I have 10 REST Endpoints to be exposed .

Should i go with creating 10 Lambda Function along with API Gateways endpoint. Or Should i create an Microservice will all these endpoint and get that Microservice deployed over ECS.

What approach would be the best.

Answer (score 0):

If you use AWS ECS its a little bit change the code and you should know how to dockerize rest api to container.

If you want to use lambda function, basically you have to reproduce whole the code.

Both of them that needs an aws devops engineer to get it done.

Comment: , Appreciate your response. Could you let me know, which one would be the best approach to adopt.

Comment: lambda is a good choice in your case, because its serverless so you do not need to manage  server, but you have to change code so much and have some knowledge about lambda function and api gateway